# UILongPressGestureRecognizer iOS for continuous action

Tags: ios, xcode, gesture, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I have a button, and I want to "press down and hold" the button so it will keep printing "Long Press" until I release the key press.

I have this in the ViewDidLoad:

```
[self.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

and

```
- (void)longPress: (UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.state == UIControlEventTouchDown) {
      NSLog(@"Long Press!");
    }
}
```

I have also tried this:

```
 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
 lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 0.1;
 lpgr.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
 [self.btn addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
```

It only prints out Long Press! once even when I hold down the button.
Can anyone tell me where I did wrong or what I missed?
Thanks!

Comment: Do not post code as images. Copy and paste the code into your question. Then be sure you format it correctly.

Comment: So, what happens? Is your handleLongPressGesture method being called?

Comment: It is being called if I remove "if ([sender isEqual: self.lpgr])", but it will only delete backward once.

Comment: I am not sure but try increasing minimum press duration....just a workaround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, **UIButton**'s target-action pair callback only execute **once** when correspond events fire.

The **UILongPressGestureRecognizer** need to a **minimumPressDuration** to get into **UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan** state, then when finger move, callback will fire with **UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged** state. At last, **UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded** state when release finger.

Your requirement is repeatedly fire when button pressed down. None of the top class satisfy your need. Instead, you need to set a **repeat fire timer** when button press down, and release it when button release up.

so the code should be:

```
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(touchBegin:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(touchEnd:) forControlEvents:
        UIControlEventTouchUpInside | UIControlEventTouchUpOutside | UIControlEventTouchCancel];

- (void)touchBegin:(UIButton*)sender {
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(longPress:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)touchEnd:(UIButton*)sender {
    [_timer invalidate];
    _timer = nil;
}

- (void)longPress:(NSTimer*)timer {
    NSLog(@"Long Press!");
}
```

By the way, neither **UIButton** nor **UILongPressGestureRecognizer** have a state with type **UIControlEvents**

Comment: But this only prints out Long Press! for 0.1 second long. If I want to keep printing until touch ends, what should I put in in TimeInterval?

Comment: @CathyOun You can change the interval